# Will software in Ubuntu work in Xubuntu as well?

Tags: xubuntu

I've just recently installed Xubuntu 12.04 on my 10 year laptop and on my Acer Aspire One netbook and I'm wondering if the software that I run in Ubuntu 12.04 will also work in Xubuntu. I would think that it would work because they're very similar but I want to be sure about this.

Comment: Yes it will work 100%

Comment: You should see this en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desktop_environment .

Comment: @nikhil: no, that is not true. See my answer...

Comment: @xubuntix thanks for pointing that. I'll downvote your answer.

Comment: @nikhil: strange reaction. Care to say why?

Comment: @xubuntix because I believe that your answer doesn't answer the question that the OP has. Also the desktop environment is just the cosmetic look and feel, the underlying OS is the same and so are the repositories from which all the software is available. Just because xfce uses thunrar instead of nautilus by default doesn't change this fact.

Comment: For the record, I'm a little bit of a noob when it comes to Ubuntu. I kind of figured that the programs would work but I just wanted to have someone here tell me that it's true, just to make sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No**, not all software that works on Ubuntu 12.04 will work on Xubuntu 12.04.

You have to understand the differences between Ubuntu and Xubuntu are mainly the desktop environments: that means that most programs run just fine, except they are specific to the desktop environment and the corresponding programs (these are e.g. a different filemanager (nautilus | thunar), different window managers (unity-compiz | xfwm4) and so on).

So: **if** the software you are talking about needs specifically the window-manager or filemanager etc. then this software will not run without problems on Xubuntu.
You will definitely be able to run those programs on Xubuntu, but that might come with problems (like filemanager switching, which might replace the icons on the desktop etc.).

The answers by the other authors probably relate to general programs like libreoffice, firefox, etc, which are not relying on specific desktop environments.

Comment: I'm 100% sure that thunar runs just as fine in Ubuntu as it does in Xubuntu. While of course XFWM4 will wreck Unity because of the simple fact that Unity is a compiz plug in and it needs Compiz running. But aside from that the rest of what comprises XFCE works 100% in Ubuntu.

Comment: I think the question is the other way round. I used Xubuntu a lot, and working with nautilus and some panel plugins (then the gnome-panel) has always been a problem under Xubuntu. The same happened now with the messaging plugin: in Xubuntu 12.10 it is not working. SO: It is not 100%, but of cause a large percentage.

Comment: I have too, and I have too used Nautilus in Xubuntu, (Thunar is just..lacking) never had a problem with any applets, the panel, the desktop, etc. I've actually replaced some components by those of other environments (like Gala instead of XFWM4). The messaging menu works fine for me, it worked/works with Empathy, Pidgin.

Comment: For the messaging menu, I was just referring to the Xubuntu teams announcement on the FAQ page: "Due to constraints unavoidable by the Xubuntu team the messaging menu is not available in Xubuntu 12.10, you must use Xubuntu 12.04 if you wish to have this menu/indicator."

Answer (score 3):

Yes all the software that work on Ubuntu 12.04 will definitely work on Xubuntu 12.04, after all both these Operating Systems are based on same Debian and Ubuntu base.

Answer (score 0):

I think the bigger question is what software you are you wanting to install? IF it's a very heavy resource app, there might be an issue with speed.